# Compare BCrypt-ed password from mobile app

Tags: c#, security, bcrypt

I'd like to verify this with some security expert.

I have a web app where I register users. I Bcrypt the pw with a unique salt for each user and store the hashed pw to the DB.

I now need to authenticate user from a mobile app. I can't use ssl and I'd prefer to avoid passing passwords in clears between mobile and my web server. So before call the login method (via RESTful API) on the server, I'd prefer to BCrypt the pw on mobile and then pass it hashed to the server via API to compare.

The point is that on the mobile I have to BCrypt with the same salt (as far as I know I cannot compare two BCrypted pw hashed with different salt).

**So the question is: is it ok and safe to**

1. Mobile asks the salt for user X to server (I get the first 22 chars plus offset from stored pw in DB)
2. On mobile I BCrypt the pw with the salt got at point 1
3. Finally mobile calls login(username, hashedpw) on server.

As said all communications are over plain http, no SSL.

Does this makes sense?

Comment: In all probability, SSL is the simplest safe solution you can opt for. If it seems like lots of work, you can rest assured that reimplementing it will not be less work ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your scheme "hashedpw" becomes a simple password, which you then store in the database unencrypted.

All that one needs to log into your server is to know (say, from intercepting) the hashed value and the username. In your implementation hashing is irrelevant to security, it is more of a memory aid to the end user but does not provide any security benefits.

Comment: If the intercept the plain pw they can (1) login via the web app and (2) the plain pw is exposed. If they intercept the hashedpw they (1) cannot login via web app, (2) the plain password is not stolen and (3) they could use it to login via the rest API but there there's another layer of security (apikey, apisecret). That's why I thought that's better than sending plain pw. I wonder if I should worry about intercepting between mobile and web server at all..

Comment: Are apikey and apisecret per user or are they static? If they can be extracted from your app'd executable, they do not add security. The difference "can login via web" vs "can login via REST" only matters if REST operations are very limited compared to the ones accessible "via web app"